# Intellij Color Scheme HTML TEXT background color

Tags: colors, html, text-editors, intellij-idea

I'm currently using a custom color scheme and i was able to find everything else to fix except one thing.

Image below is an example of it in the work. I've looked everywhere for hours and was not able to find where exactly i can change background color of text in HTML. I've looked at Language Defaults and color scheme settings.

[image: Normal text has background color of black]

Thank you very much.

EDIT: 
What color scheme are you using? 
- I am using Frantic Color scheme (Rainglow).

Theme?
- Material UI theme.

HTML Code foreground / background: (obv not black)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnCPn.png)

Thanks again.

Comment: "HTML Code" -> "Background"/ "Foreground" ?

Comment: @slhck Edited and added some info.
Thank you

Comment: @user996142 Added image to the OP. Doesn't match with what's going on.